# accessing a quick part with a variable in vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I currently have a Quick Part in word2007 named "test".  It just produces a test sentence.  I access it in vba like so:

```
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("test").Insert where:= _
             Selection.Range, RichText:=True
```

which works fine.

I was hoping I can make the ("test") part a variable like so:

```
dim x as string
x = "test"
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(x).Insert where:= _
            Selection.Range, RichText:=True
```

but it gives me an error of "argument not optional".  Is there a way to make this work using a variable?
thanks.

Comment: Try declaring `x` as `Variant`